# React: Loop through array of strings

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a bit new to reactJs, I have an array of notes I want to display in the component;

```
data: {
    title: 'notes for ABC', 
    notes: ['hello', 'world', 'blah blah]
}
```

When I try rendering this as `data.notes.map` it said data.notes.map is not a function.
Any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how you're planning on getting your data to your component but this example is how you could do it via the state. If you're having a specific component rendering a post or note, it would be better to do it via props. I would read the [List and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) docs for React.

#### Class Style

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
    this.state = { 
      notes: ['hello', 'world', 'blah blah'] 
    };
  }

  render() {
    const noteItems = this.state.notes.map((note) =>
      <li>{note}</li>
    );
    return (
      <ul>{noteItems}</ul>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

#### Functional Style

It seems like the functional way of writing this is more preferred, this is how you would write that.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState(['hello', 'world', 'blah blah'])
  return <ul>{notes.map((note) => <li>{note}</li>)}</ul>
}

export default App;

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```